# Issue with ear deployment on jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Tags: deployment, jboss7.x

I am deploying ear on jboss-as-7, it has two ejb jars and one war file. Below is the structure of application.xml file.

```
<module>
    <ejb>ejb1.jar</ejb>
</module>
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>web1.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>root/test</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
<module>
    <ejb>ejb2.jar</ejb>
</module>
```

This ear deployment requires external library dependency so I have added dependency in 
jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
   <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
   <deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="deployment.local.fwk" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>
   </deployment>
  <module name="deployment.local.fwk">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="myclasses.jar"/> 
    </resources>
  </module> 
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I have this jar file in module/local/fwk folder. I am not sure what is missing here, while deploying I am getting NoClassDefFoundError for classes which are present in myclasses.jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed documentation of how the classes are loaded is specified at

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Since you set the ear-subdeployments-isolated to true, did you set Class-Path entry in the Manifest file.

"*If the ear-subdeployments-isolated is set to true then no automatic module dependencies between the sub-deployments are set up. User must manually setup the dependency with Class-Path entries, or by setting up explicit module dependencies.*"